# how to draw a line in windows store apps

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, line

I am trying to create an application which should consist of a line drawn when keyboard key is pressed. When the left arrow in the keyboard is pressed then the line should move in left direction. When right arrow in the keyboard is pressed then the respective line should move in right direction.

I think it is possible with `Path` class but I don't know how to implement. Even I don't know how to start the code. Can you please guide me how to draw the line in windows store apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
private PathGeometry DrawGeometry()
    {

        bool largeArc = WedgeAngle > 180.0;
        Size outerArcSize = new Size(Radius, Radius);
        Size innerArcSize = new Size(InnerRadius, InnerRadius);

        Point innerArcStartPoint = Utilities.ComputeCartesianCoordinate(RotationAngle, InnerRadius);
        Point ButtomLineEndPoint = Utilities.ComputeCartesianCoordinate(RotationAngle, Radius);
        Point OuterArcEndPoint = Utilities.ComputeCartesianCoordinate(RotationAngle + WedgeAngle, Radius);
        Point EndLineEndPoint = Utilities.ComputeCartesianCoordinate(RotationAngle + WedgeAngle, InnerRadius);


        innerArcStartPoint.X += CentreX;
        innerArcStartPoint.Y += CentreY;
        ButtomLineEndPoint.X += CentreX;
        ButtomLineEndPoint.Y += CentreY;
        OuterArcEndPoint.X += CentreX;
        OuterArcEndPoint.Y += CentreY;
        EndLineEndPoint.X += CentreX;
        EndLineEndPoint.Y += CentreY;


        PathFigure path = new PathFigure();
        path.StartPoint = innerArcStartPoint;


        ArcSegment InnerArc = new ArcSegment();
        InnerArc.Size = innerArcSize;
        InnerArc.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
        InnerArc.Point = innerArcStartPoint;
        InnerArc.IsLargeArc = largeArc;

        LineSegment ButtomLine = new LineSegment();
        ButtomLine.Point = ButtomLineEndPoint;
        ArcSegment OuterArc = new ArcSegment();
        OuterArc.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
        OuterArc.Point = OuterArcEndPoint;
        OuterArc.Size = outerArcSize;
        OuterArc.IsLargeArc = largeArc;
        LineSegment EndLine = new LineSegment();
        EndLine.Point = EndLineEndPoint;
        path.Segments.Add(ButtomLine);
        path.Segments.Add(OuterArc);
        path.Segments.Add(EndLine);
        path.Segments.Add(InnerArc);

        PathGeometry myPath = new PathGeometry();
        myPath.Figures.Add(path);
        return myPath;
    }
```

This code will Draw a Pie slice for you as I was building a PieChart it Containsn Lines Curves etc. It will save lots of your time